# JSP Download Csv File

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I'm working on the problem for almost one day,and I can't figure out a solution.

I want to add a download service into my jsp page,and the code like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=authData"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())+".csv");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

and I use a trigger button to link to background.and the codes like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn_sure fw" value="query"  onclick="queryAuthDataList();"/> 
<input type="reset" class="btn_cancel fw" value="reset"> 
<input type="submit" class="btn_sure fw" value="download CSV" onclick="exportAuthDataList();" >
```

and the following onclick funtion like this:

```
function exportAuthDataList(){
        $("#queryAuthDataForm").attr("action","export").submit();
        }
    function queryAuthDataList(){
        $("#queryAuthDataForm").attr("action","query").submit();
        }
```

**for some reasons , I must use GET to collect the tag names and values in jsp file.**

Here comes the problem,when I select data from DB2,and there're many results,I must paging them,**But** when I click next page,it's starting download csv file automaticly.I define different redirect keywords in Jquery,but I can't simplely add jquery function in the "next page" link.Because I may get some other links.

How can I stop the file downloading when I click a different link ?